# background with image not working on blank span

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to put an arrow from the image to the left of a span. I am using a blank span for image and assigning background image to it. But still the image is not being shown.

```css
ul {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.expand-icon
{
 width: 15px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 float: left;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 height: auto;
 background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png");
}

.edit-list-span {
 border: 1px solid #3465a4;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myUL">
  <li class="edit-list">
    <span class="expand-icon"></span>
    <span class="edit-list-span" contenteditable="true">Test Span</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`.expand-icon` is the span where is am trying to put image but its not showing. Please help me getting around this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make the `li` `display: flex;` and set the right `span` to `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1 0 0;` for short, then fix your background properties so it's sized and positioned.

```css
ul {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.edit-list {
  display: flex;
}

.expand-icon
{
 width: 15px;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png") 0 center no-repeat / 100%;
}

.edit-list-span {
 border: 1px solid #3465a4;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow:hidden;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myUL">
  <li class="edit-list">
    <span class="expand-icon"></span>
    <span class="edit-list-span" contenteditable="true">Test Span</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But you don't need 2 spans. You can put the background in one, or just the `li`.

```css
ul {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.edit-list-span {
 border: 1px solid #3465a4;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png") 0 center no-repeat #fff / 20px 20px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myUL">
  <li class="edit-list">
    <span class="edit-list-span" contenteditable="true">Test Span</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to keep arrow out of the text span, so using separate span. But as per you first suggestion to use flex, when I am doing that the other UI is getting completely changed. I have put small snippet here where my code is repetition of such many units.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar where's the snippet?

Comment: I meant in the question, the snippet is a part of my code.

Comment: What do you mean "the other UI is getting completely changed"? What other "UI"?

Comment: Using display: flex is breaking other things in my code. The position of other elements gets disturbed. maybe I need to update display properties of other child elements of the li on which I am using flex.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar obviously. You've said that, but "the other ui is getting completely changed" and "the position of other elements gets disturbed" is meaningless to me. You aren't telling me **what is happening** and more importantly, you aren't **showing me with code**. How do you expect me to help if I can't see it? You want me to guess? I'm not going to do that, it isn't productive for either of us. You need to **show me the problem**

Comment: I wanted to create exact code situation which was breaking at that time but sorry my code has updated a lot. But accepting this as it is actual solution of the asked problem and is working in snippet while I have used the solution in other answer which is though a workaround but worked immediately for me then.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar cool thanks for the update. I'm not sure if this is the problem, but my css applied `.edit-list { display: flex; }`. You might try just using `style="display: flex;"` on the element in the HTML itself instead of applying it to the class, in case applying it to the class is what's messing up other elements.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the image because it is `128x128` and it has a transparent area surrounding it. You can add the image in the span, instead of making it the background, and change the size of the image at `.expand-icon img`

I hope this will clarify it for you

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.expand-icon
{
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  min-height: 1px;
}
.expand-icon img {
  width: 1.5em;
}

.edit-list-span {
  border: 1px solid #3465a4;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myUL">
  <li class="edit-list">
    <span class="expand-icon">
      
    </span>
    <span class="edit-list-span" contenteditable="true">
      Test Span
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when the image is removed from span, the next span shifts left. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Put the span with the image inside the other span. See the code I updated above.

Comment: no no. I dont want to overlap both spans. I mean when img tag was inside .expand-icon as was case in your old snippet then it was fine. But if I remove img tag keeping span blank, the width of .expand-icon reduces and .edit-list-span shifts left. So i want to know is there way to keep width of .edit-list fixed with image or no image inside.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. To do so, make expand-icon `width: 1.5em;` and `min-height: 1px;`. This way the div will still take up the space without a `<img />` in it. (See snippet)